# program complexity of nested loops

Tags: algorithm

I have found the following algorithm:

```
for i in range(1, n)
    for j in range(i+1,n+1)
           for k in range(1,j+1)
               //some instructions
```

and I would like to determine its complexity, so far what I have done is the following:

I have converted the three loops into summations so I have

[image]

so when I analize the loops j and k it is easy to see that when j starts with 2 then k with make 2 loops, when j starts with 3 then k will do 3 loops, and so on. At this poing I can have something like:

[image]

I am considering c as the instructions that are inside the k loop. For finishing I can say that I have:

[image]

Is this analysis correct or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Result is OK, it's O(n^3)

Comment: The figure you derived is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are O(n^3) steps here, as you believe. Your heuristic has shown that O(n^3) is an upper bound --- but one might ask if it is a tight upper bound. In fact, it is (assuming that the content of each loop is essentially a constant-time operation).

One way to see this is to make some loose upper and lower bounds.

For an upper bound, note that i ranges from 1 to n, j ranges over a *subset* of 1 to n+1, and k ranges over a *subset* of 1 to n+2. There are then fewer steps than if i, j, and k ran over (1,n), (1,n+1), and (1,n+2), respectively. And this is O(n^3) steps. Thus there are at most O(n^3) steps. I note that this is roughly the heuristic that you used to produce your answer.

For a lower bound, we can note that when i is in (n/3, 2n/3), the j index will always include the range (2n/3 + 1, n + 1). And for i and j in these ranges, the k index will always include the range (1, 2n/3 + 2). The lengths of these ranges are n/3 (for i), n/3 (for j), and 2n/3 + 1 (for k). This is also of order n^3, and so O(n^3) is the right estimate. Some people would then say that this is BigTheta(n^3).